# Inline styling classes for variable count of <img>

Tags: html, css, class, html-email, styling

I am creating an email notification for when someone posts to a Sharepoint Blog. The body of this post is automatically included in the email notification using a lookup in a sharepoint workflow. This Body includes a different number(count) of images each time (ranging from 0-20).
To email using a workflow the requirment is: **All styling (CSS) must be inline** and must be in string form. eg.

```
<html><head><title>Hello World!</title></head><body><p style="color: #000000;"></p></body>
```

The way the blog post is inserted:

```
 <td>[%Current Item: Body%]</td>
```

The body of the blog post (including images) is inserted in html format instead of the "[%Current Item: Body%]" by the workflow. The images are regular html image tags.

What I would like to do is style each of the inserted img tags (variable count), preferably as a class. What can I do so that I can style these image tags without being able to edit each individual tag as I am unable to do this (all handled by the workflow). Especially I am looking to be able to set max width:height for these images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using wide selector in inline style block

   ```
   <style type="text/css">
        td img { max-width:200px; }
   </style>
   ```
2. depending on code generated, if for example it adds a class like `class="some[01]"` you can do :

   ```
   img[class=^"some"] { max-width: 200px; }
   ```

Comment: Unfortunatley the workflow does not generate classes for html.
How can I use a wide selector inline? (sorry if this is very basic)

Comment: unfortunately you can't use wide selectors inline, but should work on all email browsers if you just declare on top `<style></style>` block and place the css rule inside